# PHP create image to display email address?

Tags: php, image-generation

Using PHP: How can I create an image to display an email address (to help reduce spam)?

Meaning, if I want to display "joe@example.com" on my web page, since crawlers can easily find that text - I want to display the email address as an image that says "joe@example.com".

How do I do that? I want the font to be:

- color: #20c
- font: 11px normal tahoma

Answer (score 4):

A simple search that you could easily do....

However: (color, font and string not the ones you specified)

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Relevant function definitions:

[php.net/imagecreate](http://pt2.php.net/imagecreate)

[php.net/imagestring](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use these:

- [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), to tell the browser to expect an image instead of HTML (PHP's default). The image function doc pages have more information about this.
- [imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php), to find out the required size for the image
- [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), to create the image resource
- [imagecolorallocate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php), to allocate a color for the text
- [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php), to draw the text (read the example, it's almost all you need)
- [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), to output the image to the browser

Comment: +1 But please make it a list with some additional information why/how to use these functions.

Comment: The documentation links should be enough for anyone who can be bothered to spend five minutes reading.

Comment: Thought it would be obvious since each and every one of those documentation pages has it, but here you go...

Answer (score 0):

You should use gd image processing library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing this for one address you should not be doing this dynamically everytime the page loads for performance reasons. If this is the case you can find amny email obfuscator online such as this one:

http://digitalcolony.com/lab/maskemail/maskemail.aspx

Comment: No, I'm doing this for hundreds of email addresses